# WPF WebBrowser not including the hash in the source url?

Tags: .net, wpf, facebook, browser

I'm currently trying to make a log in for facebook users into my WPF application. It's using .net 4 and it's being developed in VS2010. After following the [steps stated in the facebook developers page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/desktop) I cannot get it working. The success url should be followed by a hash (#) and the access_token after the login, but `webbrowser.Source.toString()` is not including that.
I made *exactly the same*, but in a winforms app and it does work fine.

Is there something else to do with the WPF webbrowser control? Is that an issue related to redirects to anchors when the document is loaded or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/593832/possible-bug-in-webbrowser-control-realization-in-wpf-and-windows-phone-7